# Active class not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some menu items and in the menu I have a plus(+) sign. When I click on the plus sign it should add a class and look like cross. It is happening but when I click the cross sign it does not removing the sign so that I can get the plus sign again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('.nav-link').click(function(){
    $('.nav-link').removeClass('addplus');
    $(this).addClass('addplus');
  });

});
```

Here is the [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tanmndz/epqxb6L7/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you are always removing, then immediately adding the class back on the clicked element. To fix this exclude the current element from the `removeClass()` call using `not()`, then use `toggleClass()` to add/remove the class to the required element, like this:

```js
$('.nav-link').click(function() {
  $('.nav-link').not(this).removeClass('addplus');
  $(this).toggleClass('addplus');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/epqxb6L7/3/)

Comment: This is a better and much more concise method than the one I've supplied. Nice.

Comment: @mr.tanmay no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I've gone a bit around about the houses here, but this works using `parent` and `siblings`:

```
$('.nav-link').click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".nav-item").siblings().children(".nav-link").removeClass('addplus');
    $(this).toggleClass('addplus');
});
```

I wouldn't do a blanket `removeClass` across all matching elements like you've done, I'd pick them out by excluding the currently matched element. Revised fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/epqxb6L7/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code is removing and adding the same class every time click event triggers. Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('.nav-link').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('addplus'); //THIS WILL ADD/REMOVE CLASS ALTERNATIVELY
  });
});
```

Comment: partly wrong you are saying. Because when I click on the 1st menu its good and when i click second menu it also doing that but it does not removing the 1st menu's sign

Answer (score 0):

You **always** add the class `addplus` in the last line of your click handler. Try the following instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('.nav-link').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('addplus')) {
      $(this).removeClass('addplus');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('addplus');
    }
  });
});
```